# Accessing DLNA over VPN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have set up a VPN server using OpenVPN on my home Ubuntu 10 box as a means to access my home network drives and media drives whilst at work and on the move. I get a valid connection, can ping and connect to any node on the network successfully, I can access my network drives, but not the media drive.

A bit of digging suggests that this is something to do with 'multicasting' accross the VPN. I can't seem to find any information on this, and cant seem to find any settings in the OpenVPN config nor options files.

If multicasting needs to be enabled somehow, how can I achieve this? If I am missing the issue here, can someone enlighten me on my failures?

Thanks guys and girls.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. Unfortunately your question doesn't appear to be on topic here as it doesn't have any apparent relation to **professional** system or network administration. It may be on topic at our sister site [su] but check their FAQ and About page first, and search to see if your question may already have been answered there.

Comment: Thank you Michael, thats my mistake; I did not know Super User existed and thought serverFault was the best fitting place to ask this. Sorry about the misplacement.

Comment: @kirgy Another place to ask (specifically because you're talking about an Ubuntu box) might be [ubuntu.SE] - assuming you haven't been able to turn up anything helpful on Google (there are lots of OpenVPN client tutorials out there, there's a good chance one of them could point you in the right direction)

Comment: Thanks @voretaq7, I've found a fair few nice tutorials which have helped me get this server running smoothly, unfortunately Google hasnt been as helpful as I imagined, I'll head over to Ask Ubuntu, that sounds like a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

In order to tunnel multicast packets, You'll need to use a GRE tunnel. The same obstacle exists for routing mDNS/Bonjour/ZeroConf packets.

There are plenty of tutorials, though many provide slighty different versions of whats allowed an whats not (by far the most challenging thing about GRE is the lack of quality consistant information).

[Ubuntu GRE tutorial](http://onvox.net/linux/how-to-create-ipv4-gre-tunnels-in-ubuntu)